# Angular Not Posting to URI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

My angular code is not posting to the api when I enter data in a form even though my api has been proven to work and takes curl CRUD requests. The register function is called from my partial, then Register controller uses the user service and register function to post form the model to the api

user service

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);

    UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function UserService($http) {
        var service = {};

        service.GetAll = GetAll;
        service.GetById = GetById;
        service.GetByUsername = GetByUsername;
        service.Create = Create;
        service.Update = Update;
        service.Delete = Delete;

        return service;

        function GetAll() {
            return $http.get('https://me.com/api/users/').then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting all users'));
        }

        function GetById(id) {
            return $http.get('https://me.com/api/users/' + id).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error getting user by id'));
        }
...

    function Create(user) {
        return $http.post('https://me.com/api/users', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
    }

.....
```

Register Partial

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterController as vm">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.register()" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.fname.$dirty && form.fname.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.fname" required />
            <span ng-show="form.fname.$dirty && form.fname.$error.required" class="help-block">First name is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.lname.$dirty && form.lname.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="Text1" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.lname" required />
            <span ng-show="form.lname.$dirty && form.lname.$error.required" class="help-block">Last name is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.hashword.$dirty && form.hashword.$error.required }">
            <label for="hashword">Password</label>
            <input type="hashword" name="hashword" id="hashword" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.hashword" required />
            <span ng-show="form.hashword.$dirty && form.hashword.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,..." />
            <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
```

Register controller/function

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['UserService', '$location', '$rootScope', 'FlashService'];
    function RegisterController(UserService, $location, $rootScope, FlashService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.register = register;

        function register() {
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            UserService.Create(vm.user)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
                        $location.path('/login');
                    } else {
                        FlashService.Error(response.message);
                        vm.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
        return false;
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Please show your `UserService.Create` method. How do you know that it doesn't make a POST request? What the console tells you?

Comment: the console is empty when i do this yet when i curl it it works and the api is updated

Comment: Do you return false at the end of the register function? If not then this is your problem, since you are actually submitting the form

Comment: Added that it and still error.... :( may post a plunkr

Comment: there is no post in the code you provided... Please, provide the `UserService.Create` code

Comment: no need to add return false with ngSubmit

Comment: @n00dl3 , julian UserService.Create method up

Comment: @sz tech is right is right, did you specify something like `ng-controller="RegisterController as vm"` in your html ? Because `vm` is not bound to the scope here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you assign your controller to the view? Did you use the `controller as` syntax? For example: 
`<div ng-controller="RegisterController as vm">your view here </div>`
You are assigning the register function to `vm` but the vm is just a local variable in the controller function so angular is not able to use its functions in view.
Assigning `this` to local vm variable is a good practice, better than using $scope everywhere, but it's still just a local variable inside the controller function's scope. If you assign your controller to view and rename your controller (`<div ng-controller="RegisterController as vm">`), then it will work.

Comment: Ok I added that in. It still doesn't post to api for some reason. What do you mean by assign my controller to view? Wondering what I'm missing

Comment: Can you confirm that you can reach the register function now? You can assign a controller in two ways via `$routeProvider` or via `ng-controller`, it means that you can choose which controller function's scope should be used in a specific view. Could you share your entire form code with us, please?

Comment: thanks and yes I can reach the register function..just trying to now understand why the post isn't being sent properly if at all

Comment: can you show your code for the `register` function?